# window.onload() is not firing with IE 8 in first shot

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make my pages work correctly with IE 8, I found out from here: http://www.masykur.web.id/post/How-to-Make-Our-Website-to-be-Ready-for-IE8.aspx
that, my page has to be XHTML 1.0 compliant and atleast CSS 2.1 compliant, I made my page and CSS compliant with only few warnings, but still window.onload() is not firing. Does anybody encountered this problem?

here is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function()
            {
                          // Not coming here at all on first shot   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     .
     .
     .
```

However refreshing the page seems to make it work.

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE:**

One of the IE addons created this problem, after disabling its working fine. Thanks for your time and answers :)

Comment: If you're opening the file locally, as in from the filesystem, IE might be trying to protect you from security issues?

Comment: yes, I am not complaining about that. But a simple HTML file with an window.onload is not working with IE 8, if I use a webserver like Apache and I am not able to figure out why!

Comment: Are there some flash in yout page?
The flash addon causes the problema. With some old versions of flash player the problem doesnt occur.

Comment: @Manohar Can you say which addon was doing the problem ? I am also facing the same issue with IE9.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani, It was a custom plugin that we had developed for some purpose which caused the problem. The best solution would be to remove *all* the plugins

Answer (score 28):

For IE try:

```
window.onload = new function() { alert('hello');};
```

Comment: this executes the function immediately as a side-effect of new. onload gets set to the result of the object creation! (new object)

Comment: You might as well just remove the `onload` completely then and just wrap in an IIFE or something like that.  This will not behave the same as onload.

Answer (score 9):

This is a pretty old thread but I found a solution that might help others.

I was adding a function to `window.onload` via a dynamically injected script (really to mimic an external script load for reasons which are not important in this context). As stated in this post, on the first load within IE8, the `window.onload` would not fire, but all subsequent calls would.

I found out that if I put this in the HTML file as an internal script, it would work everytime:

```
var windowOnload = window.onload || function() {};
window.onload = function() { windowOnload(); };
```

All the above code does is "initializes" IE8's `window.onload` unobtrusively.  I suspect that IE8 fails to trigger `window.onload` the first time if it is called from an external script as the `onload` event isn't attached yet to window (or in tech terms, its typeof is undefined).  It seems that the first time that's what IE8 is doing: attaching `onload` to window without executing it properly.

The above code then becomes quite obvious:  We are merely forcing IE8 to recognize the `onload` event.  We don't care what gets executed, or what doesn't, so we simply make sure to pipe on through any existing `window.onload` code that is already defined (just as a precaution).

It is important to have this as an internal script to the HTML (at least from my testing).

Your HTML would thus look something like this (the relevant parts):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var windowOnload=window.onload||function(){};window.onload=function(){windowOnload();};
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
 </script>
```

From my testing, after clearing cache, and reloading the page, I have gotten `window.onload` to successfully trigger each time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could have an error in your JavaScript's, if that happens, any JavaScript after that will not function correctly.

Try to remove the reference to login.js and common.js and try an alert within your problematic function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have IE8 to personally test, but what does this test do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test IE 8</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.onload = function(){alert('Good morning!');}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<body>
</html>
```

If this test works as expected, try the CDATA bit around your internal JavaScript block.

And then, if that does not work as expected, there is probably something in the external JavaScript above it that prevents your onload from firing. The previous poster mentioned this. At that point, try your error console or debugger to point the way.

Answer (score 1):

onload fires after ALL your content has loaded (including external images etc). It's possible those resources are taking a long time to load on the first go (before they are cached). Another possibility is an error in your code that only affects IE as is stopping your scripts (but only the first time is odd).

Comment: First possibility is ruled out since, onload I am just calling a javascript function which sets a number. I am looking into any errors in my code, I just wrote a sample code which is working fine in IE 8 with onload (however onload content is blocked with this error: 'To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this website from running scripts...' everytime, I have to "Allow" to make it work).

Comment: I found out that if Apache is rendering the page, onload is not firing. I have a sample code that can demonstrate this.

Comment: I think you might misunderstand. It doesn't matter what your onload handler actually does, what matters is it won't even run _until_ every page element has "loaded" (not just the html, but external CSS, JS and images). If IE is getting stuck downloading an external resource or running inline JS then it hasn't "loaded" and your script won't fire. You may have a loop somewhere in your code that is preventing "loading" from completing.

Comment: but more likely some interaction with Apache is blocking a resource from downloading. Do you have any modrewrite rules that may be affecting content?

Comment: PS. In particular look for anything that may be causing redirects or recusion.

Comment: Actually there was a IE plugin which was causing this problem. I never knew plugins could cause this sort of problems until now :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting different results using Apache vs. another web server (IIS?) and comparing the end result using IE8, then the differrence must be in the content type header being sent.  Get the wget utility for your platform and see the headers that are produced.  If you are on Windows, then the [Portable Apps version of the GUI wget](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/winwget_portable) is pretty nice.

Comment: I have not tried in IIS, I have tried in apache only and its not working for me, I tried using window.onload = new Function("alert('!');"); also, even this is not firing in IE-8.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.  When I load the page in Firefox I see the alert instantly.  When I first load the page in IE 8 it warns me about active content.  If I allow the blocked content it asks me to confirm, which I do.  Then the alert appears as expected.  If this does not work for you, try IE 8 on a different computer or start eliminating code in your page to check for errors.  You could do a binary search: comment out the first half of the page and see if the alert appears; if it still does not, then uncomment out the first half and comment out the second half.  Repeat as needed until you've narrowed it down to the offending code.  Incidentally you don't need XHTML for IE8 compliance.  HTML works fine and actually has some advantages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function() { alert('hello');};
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does work as you describe if I derectly open the HTML file with IE 8. But when I put the same file in apache and access it through the server, onload is not firing for the first time. I have to manually refresh everytime to make the code block in onload to work. I have not yet tried in different machines. I will try and update here.

Comment: I suspect it's related to xhtml then. Try using regular HTML.

Comment: I should add: if it is an XHTML problem, the solution might be Fran Cooper's solution, which is to put CDATA wrappers around the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old question, but I just faced the same thing.

```
 window.onload=function() { alert('hello');};
```

is treated differently than

```
 window.onload= new function() { alert('hello');};
```

The keyword here is `new`.

My JS was terminating whenever it reaches (onload=) part until I added the word'new' before 'function'. Even though it worked fine without 'new' in my localhost, but once I put it online, it doesn't work until I add 'new'.

Comment: the 2nd version runs the new function immediately, since calling new will create a 'new' object with function() as the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I had the same issue but it turned out to be another problem. My problem was that I did `<script type="application/javascript">` which `<IE9` does not understand or try to run even. For it to work for older browsers you still have to use `text/javascript` even though this isn't technically the correct type...