# JavaScript - IE8 window.onload() is not working in new opened window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, window.open

this post is related to [window.onload() is not firing with IE 8 in first shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886668/window-onload-is-not-firing-with-ie-8-in-first-shot).

From within the main page (window) I open a new window:

```
... window.open('foobar.php',<...>); ...
```

The new window is opened correctly but the code within the window.onload() section (located in 'foobar.php') is not executed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>foobar</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   window.onload = function ()
   {
      alert('foobar');
   }
   //]]>
   </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The replacement of "window.onload" by Prototype's "document.observe('dom:loaded', function()" and the "onload" attribute in the body-Tag do not work, too. If I reload the content of the new opened window or open it again then the code is working correctly. If I run the code from within the main window then the code is working correctly, too. It seems to be a caching problem but I'm not sure.

My IE version is 8.0.6001.18702. I have put off all Add-Ons.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry that was a little bit unclear.

    window.open('foobar.php');

The code above is located in 'foobar.php'.

Comment: Please post exact code of the `window.open`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the script is in the page that was ALREADY LOADED, the onload event happened long ago.

There is a difference between when the window has loaded and when the DOM is ready.