# Page load in IE, page includes flash banner

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer

So here is the problem.

I have a flash banner consisting of two swf's which talk to each other through LocalConnection and also call external JS functions. (I haven't figured out whether this is important or just a coinsedense.)

I also have an external JS file, which tells the banner what to do through flashVars. And has the function which the banner calls on events.

As you can imagine this works everywhere allright except IE.

In IE I expirience this problem: I try to load a test page, which has a lot of pictures and a heavy background (so it takes a while to load). And i place the banner, which is added whith javascript before all that content. Something like this:

http://pastebin.com/nnTuPPhN

And sometimes usually on reload some pictures just do not appear. All text appears though.

I did try do dig through the script, but since it's not my script it prooved to be a bit difficult, finally I came to a conclusion that even though I don't like some parts of it, there are no apparent problems with it.

FireBug and Chrome, Safari, Opera debuggers show no errors of any kind.

Now as last resort I added this to my JS file

```
window.onload = function()
{
    alert('The page has loaded completely');
};
```

The outcome is that when i see all the pictures i see this message, when i don't i don't. It's doesn't help to wait for the pictures to load.

I have also found this topic:
[window.onload() is not firing with IE 8 in first shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886668/window-onload-is-not-firing-with-ie-8-in-first-shot)

which talks about similar problem, so it would be nice if anyone specifies what addon can cause this? QUOTE: One of the IE addons created this problem, after disabling its working fine. Thanks for your time and answers :)

As long as it isn't the flash plugin=)))

I do check for flash plugin on page this way:

```
var ad_checkPlugin = function(){
    // From SWFObject v2.2 <http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/>

    if (typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") 
    {
        d = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"].description;
        return (d && !(typeof navigator.mimeTypes != "undefined" && navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"] && !navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin))
    }

    else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined")
    {
        try
        {
            var d = new window.ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash").GetVariable("$version");
            // new window.ActiveXObject(...) will return null if ActiveX is disabled
            return d?true:false;
        } 
        catch(e) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And there was another way which caused the same problems in Ie, so i guess it's not the problem with the plugin check.

I would be happy if you tell me general things which can cause such problems, i can also ad the script if you guys ask for it.

And i will be even happier if you tell me specific things=)) , if you're going to say that problems lie whithin the script I will no be able to agree or disagree I've cheked and see no problem, browsers see no problems too. But it must be there somewhere since it doesn't work.

UPDATE: I also have alerts every where in my JS now, now what i witness is this: in FF for example sometimes i see the alert

```
alert('The page has loaded completely');
```

but I am not left any time to click this one(click ok), when another alert pops up. Is that a normal thing for alerts? I should add that many of the alerts are in function called by the banner.

UPDATE no2:

I've isolated the problem even more I stopped any calls from flash to JS functions at all (First i tried to replace them with alert("hello world"); that didn't help the loading problem).

Now when flash doesn't call to JS the page loads just fine. Of course i need the flash to call external functions.

Anyway NEW QUESTION : could javascript called from flash make IE think that everything is loaded and it can stop, that is can it be something like:

```
clean your room (and two seconds later)

now brush your teeth

result: the room is half clean but the teeth are
```

I might add that whatever loads on the page, some things load always: text, spaces fo future pictures but that may just be a coincedence, apart from this there is no system at all to what has, and what hasn't loaded.

---------------------------> ANWSER FOUND
Thanks))) for voting for my question, and here is the anwser guys! The function used in flash namely

```
getURL("javascript: ...","");
```

is what actually stops the page from loading! Hm, rather than this it's better to use ExternalInterface(); I'll point out we are talking about AS 2.0 in AS3.0 there is no question that ExternalInterface should be used, since getURL is now navigateTo or smthg.

Thanks to the guy who wrote this AS to realise what the problem was=)

Comment: I want to help, but I'm not sure what the question is any more. Did the question change? If so, what is it? And do you have a demo page (working proto) I can use to help troubleshoot?

Comment: demo page, here =) Sorry for the long question... http://banners.adfox.ru/110729/adfox/155750/testpage_moda.html  this is sufficient to stop IE loading, the question is still why it doesn't work, I just made some assumtion see last two updates

Comment: Tested with Mozilla on macOS doesn't work -> some times ExternalInterface is bad on macOS

Comment: you could postpone the onload event with a getURL("javascript: setTimeout(---what you need ---, time in miliseconds)","") and in the javascript every time you have some heavy code the call for that function should be done with setTimeout(function,0). This should basicaly permit js and flash run in the same time on the same page without freezing the browser.

Comment: you should answer your own question in the "Your Answer" section below so this can be removed from the "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying anwser from above so the question is solved

> The function used in flash namely
>
> getURL("javascript: ...",""); is what actually stops the page from
>   loading! Hm, rather than this it's better to use ExternalInterface();
>   I'll point out we are talking about AS 2.0 in AS3.0 there is no
>   question that ExternalInterface should be used, since getURL is now
>   navigateTo or smthg.