# getting 'not implemented' for window.onload in IE javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

For some reason IE is not letting me call a function from my HTML page. It says 'not implemented' in the debugger at the function addEvent. I am at a loss and would really appreciate some help.

Here is the code in my web page (underneath a 'select' tag with options for language choice)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = addEvent((document.getElementById('eng')), 'click', redirectEng);
window.onload = addEvent((document.getElementById('chs')), 'click', redirectChs);
window.onload = addEvent((document.getElementById('ger')), 'click', redirectGer);
</script>
```

Comment: Even aside from the missing `addEvent()` function that gives that error, it doesn't make sense to assign `window.onload` to three different things in a row.

Comment: the addEvent function is in a separate file. window.onload is for a language drop-down list. This program works beautifully in Firefox

Comment: but, IE isn't recognizing that the function exists from the HTML page. like I said, works great in Firefox

Comment: If you have a problem with `addEvent()` please show the implementation of `addEvent()`. If you have a problem with a function declared in another file please show the script tag that includes the other file.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you really want is this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  addEvent((document.getElementById('eng')), 'click', redirectEng);
  addEvent((document.getElementById('chs')), 'click', redirectChs);
  addEvent((document.getElementById('ger')), 'click', redirectGer);
};
```

Your code might work under FF, but it is still a very very bad code. You misunderstand concepts. Multiple assigns to `.onload`? Pointless. Also `.onload` has to be a function. Maybe FF does not throw an error ( unlike IE ), but still I'm sure that your code would work under FF without `window.onload` at all.

In that particular case I have to say it ( cause it does not happen often ): it's not IE's fault. :-)

**EDIT**

Apparently IE has some problems with `window.onload`. Read this thread:

[window.onload() is not firing with IE 8 in first shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886668/window-onload-is-not-firing-with-ie-8-in-first-shot)

for more details. For cross-browser compatibility I advice you have a look at some well-known JavaScript library, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). With jQuery the task would be as simple as:

```
$(function(){
    $( '#eng' ).click( redirectEng );
    $( '#chs' ).click( redirectChs );
    $( '#ger' ).click( redirectGet );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am very new to Javascript (only about 6 weeks), and I have to have this done for a job by Friday. Now the IE debugger says nothing is wrong, but for some reason my 'click' trigger isn't working in IE - or at least, that's the only idea I can come up with. any ideas?

Comment: You might be able to work faster if you use a framework like jQuery.