# JavaScript error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.onload() is not firing with IE 8 in first shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886668/window-onload-is-not-firing-with-ie-8-in-first-shot)

I am getting a error while running the code in JavaScript on line 20. The line 20 code is just here:

```
window.onload = setTimeout( function(){
    $('#notification_div').slideUp(2000);
} , 6000);
```

Comment: Not implemented  add_info.php line 18 character1

Comment: you trying to assign scalar to `window.onload` this is incorrect for any browsers, may be some, not throw errror on this...

Answer (score 1):

event handler should be a function,

```
window.onload = function() {setTimeout( function(){
    $('#notification_div').slideUp(2000);
} , 6000);};
```

as you using jquery, may be better to

```
$(window).load(
 function() {
  setTimeout( function(){
        $('#notification_div').slideUp(2000);
  } , 6000)
 }
);
```

Comment: thanks bro ts working now

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this

```
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout( function(){
    $('#notification_div').slideUp(2000);
  } , 6000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are missing the function in the `.onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){ //<-------missing this
   setTimeout( function(){
      $('#notification_div').slideUp(2000);
   } , 6000);
};
```

Why not use the jquery version of `.load()`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout( function(){
     $('#notification_div').slideUp(2000);
   } , 6000);
});
```