# IE8 javascript doesnt load first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have an instance of the MicroStrategy web application running on tomcat. I have performed some customizations within this application to add javascript in a

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

I am having some issues in IE8 when the page is loaded for the first time. The browser cache is cleared and the page is navigated to, for some reason the javascript will cause the page to not render the first time. If I press back(on the browser) and then forwards the page reloads 100%. Does anyone have recommendations about what I should look at?

There are no HTTP issues thrown when I ran a fiddler trace. No 404 errors or 500 on any of the content which is loaded.

note** this does not happen with 'no add-on' mode in IE

There is already an existing onLoad inline on the body

```
  <body onload="if (typeof(document.readyState) == 'undefined') document.readyState = 'complete';microstrategy.eventManager.executeFunction('microstrategy.eventManager.onload()');Init();gotoPromptAnchor();">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886668/window-onload-is-not-firing-with-ie-8-in-first-shot

Comment: Looks like he solved the issue by disabling an IE addon. That unfortunately is not an acceptable answer for me:(

Comment: The point being, if window.onload isn't working, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Browser settings which might be causing this?

Comment: ok... window.onload = function(){//code} //just tested in IE8 emulation

Comment: Is that different than $(window).bind("load", function() { ?

Comment: yes, $(window) is a Jquery object, while "window" is native js

Comment: There is an existing onload on the body